# python: cd into file

Tags: python, directory

I have a script that creates a folder `foo-12345`. Issue is, the numbers in the folder change name anytime I run a per script that creates it. I'm trying to find a way to change directory into the folder so I can do a search. I tried using a variable:

```
import os 
output = /var/foo-*
os.chdir(ouput)
```

This does not seem to work. Is there a way to capture that folder name in a variable and use that variable instead?

Comment: Where's the script that creates the random folder name? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a perl script that runs troubleshoot and generates a tarball (foo-12345.tar.gz). I am writing a script that runs the perl, unzip that tar, and go into the unzipped folder to look for specific files. I have every part except being able to log into the foo-12325 folder because the 12345 part in the name is dynamic.

Comment: You can make the perl script pass the random folder name as command line argument to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` module to do it.

```
import glob
dirs = glob.glob('/var/foo-*')
```

The resulting `dirs` is a list, so you will need to process it as such. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html)